# Difference between various contributor roles available in Azure and how to use it effectively?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, role-based-access-control

There are different type of contributor roles in Azure. If I'm giving "contributor" role at resource group level, and that resouce group has SQL Server, Storage and other resources as well.

Is it that, someone having "contributor" role to the resource group level can perform activities same as "storage account contributor"( for the given perticuler storage) and "SQL Server contributor"( for the given perticuler SQL server ) in that perticuler resource group? So that, I don't have to give any other contributor roles? My intention is here not to duplicate the roles and I can just give "contributor" role at resouce group level once and people can perform other available contributor tasks ( on storage or on SQL server) using main "contributor" role given.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *****Yes, you are on the right path**. Assigning  **`Contributor`** role at the resource group level can perform activities same as "Storage account Contributor"( for the given particular storage) and  "SQL Server contributor"( for the given particular SQL server ) in that particular resource group.***

Please **note** that, **`Contributor`** role at resource group can give access to manage any resource whereas **`Storage Account Contributor`** can give access to manage the specific resource (storage accounts).

***I tested the same scenario in my environment and got the below results:***

I assigned only **`Contributor`** role to a user at resource group level like below:

[image]

The user is able to create storage account successfully like below without having **`Storage Account Contributor`** role (having only  **`Contributor`** role).

[image]

**For more information, please refer below links:**

[Can Contributor role in Azure see the data of resources like DB, DWH & blobs? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318921/can-contributor-role-in-azure-see-the-data-of-resources-like-db-dwh-blobs)

[What is the difference between a Contributor role and Storage Account Contributor role in Azure AD? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72365318/what-is-the-difference-between-a-contributor-role-and-storage-account-contributo#:%7E:text=The%20difference%20is%20the%20scope%20of%20the%20permissions.,to%20manage%20all%20resources%20The%20storage%20account%20contributor%3A)

[Classic subscription administrator roles, Azure roles, and Azure AD roles | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#azure-rbac-roles)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it that, someone having "contributor" role to the resource group
> level can perform activities same as "storage account contributor"(
> for the given perticuler storage) and "SQL Server contributor"( for
> the given perticuler SQL server ) in that perticuler resource group?

Your understanding is correct.

> So that, I don't have to give any other contributor roles?

You can certainly do that however please keep in mind that if you assign `Contributor` role to a user on a resource group level, essentially that user will be able to manage all resources in that resource group. For example, they will be able to create VMs in that resource group.

It is highly recommended that you only grant the roles that are absolutely needed. If you want a user to manage just storage accounts and SQL databases in a resource group, then grant them only the roles needed for that purpose. If you do not want them to add new storage accounts in that resource group, then just grant Storage Account Contributor/Contributor role just for the storage account inside that resource group.